# Add "Role" attribute to POST request for worklog in jira

Tags: post, request, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to add a worklog via the jira api.I need only one more thing and that is how to add a Role to the worklog. I want the role to be "Developer"
[image]

My request is:

```
URL: https://{host}/rest/api/2/issue/{jiraticket}/worklog 

Body: {
    "comment": "Test",
    "started": "2022-11-18T14:47:10.501+0000",
    "timeSpent": "3h 15m",
 
}
```

Creating a worklog with this body works but I also need to add a role.
Is there any way to add this?

Comment: I think the logwork screen that you share is from Tempo plugin, right?

Comment: Yes, @stuck. It is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jira worklog, your endpoint and request is totally correct.

However, the log screen that you mentioned belongs to [Tempo Timesheets Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6572/tempo-timesheets-jira-time-tracking?tab=overview&hosting=cloud); so the "Role" attribute is also belong to that plugin.

For creating a Tempo worklog, you can use [Tempo Timesheets Rest API](https://apidocs.tempo.io/#tag/Worklogs/operation/createWorklog) for creating worklog.